# mscorlib.dll is always automatically referenced by the build system

Tags: .net-4.0

I tried to create a class library in .NetFrameWork 4.0.
I used the below code in a class and trying to add mscorlib.dll from .NetFrameWork 4.0 since the System.Type is residing on mscorlib.dll.

```
string str3 = (string)type.Format(str2, obj1, obj.properties.email.value);
```

But while adding the reference ,there is an error occured[image]

Anyone please help me in this

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add reference to mscorlib.dll as it is automatically refered by the build system.
For using "Type" class,all you need to do is,just use the "using System" namespace.

Check this:

[image]